# How to use embeded static Builder when product class is derived

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, polymorphism, builder

I implemented embedded static Builder for my product class and it receives another class in constructor call. This should be called in the following way:

```
 StudentFeatureBuilder studentFeatureBuilder=new  StudentFeature.StudentFeatureBuilder<StudentFeatureBuilder>(studentModel);
 StudentFeature feature=studentFeatureBuilder.build();
```

All these classes (StudentFeatureBuilder, StudentFeature and StudentModel) should be used and extended by end users, so one could create FooStudentFeatureBuilder, FooStudentFeature and FooStudentModel. All feature classes are registered with one manager class as collection, and there should be one method that will build all registered features for the provided student model. 
The only method I managed to make work is to add an additional static build method to StudentFeature and all subclasses that will use builder:

```
public static StudentFeature build(StudentModel studentModel){
    return new StudentFeatureBuilder<StudentFeatureBuilder>(studentModel).build();
}
```

Then I have the method that will trigger it like:

```
 for(Class<? extends StudentFeature> featureClass:featuresClasses){
      Method buildMethod=featureClass.getMethod("build", studentModel.getClass());
  StudentFeature feature= (StudentFeature) buildMethod.invoke(null,studentModel);
```

However, I don't like this solution as it force end user to write redundant build methods 2 times. I hope there is some more elegant solution.

Thanks,
Zoran

In addition to my original post, this is the code I have now and that seems to work.

```
//*******************************************************
//StudentFeature class
//*******************************************************
public   class StudentFeature {
private String name;
private List<StudentFeature> dependsOn;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String fName) {
    this.name = fName;
}


public List<StudentFeature> getDependsOn() {
    return dependsOn;
}
public void setDependsOn(List<StudentFeature> dependsOn) {
    this.dependsOn = dependsOn;
}
public void addDependsOn(StudentFeature dependsOn){
    if(dependsOn!=null && !this.dependsOn.contains(dependsOn)){
        this.dependsOn.add(dependsOn);
    }
}
public static class Builder<T extends Builder>{
    public Builder(){
        System.out.println("Default Feature Builder called");
    }
    public StudentFeature build(StudentModel studentModel){
        System.out.println("Build Student Feature");
        return new StudentFeature();
    }       
}

}
//*******************************************************
//FooStudentFeature class
//*******************************************************
public class FooStudentFeature extends StudentFeature{

private double value=0.0;

protected FooStudentFeature() {
}


public static class Builder extends StudentFeature.Builder<Builder> {
    StudentModel studentModel;
    public Builder(){
     System.out.println("Foo student feature builder constructor");
    }    
    public StudentFeature build(StudentModel studentModel){
        System.out.println("Build Foo Student Feature");
        return new FooStudentFeature();
    }   


}

}
//*******************************************************
//StudentModel class 
//*******************************************************
public abstract class StudentModel {
private List<StudentFeature> features;
private PersonalData personalData;

public StudentModel(){
    setFeatures(new ArrayList<StudentFeature>());
}

public List<StudentFeature> getFeatures() {
    return features;
}

public void setFeatures(List<StudentFeature> features) {
    this.features = features;
}
public void addFeature(StudentFeature feature){
    System.out.println("called add feature");
    if(feature!=null && !this.features.contains(feature)){
        System.out.println("adding feature:"+feature.getClass().getName());
        this.features.add(feature);
    }
}
public void removeFeature(StudentFeature feature){
    if(feature!=null && this.features.contains(feature)){
        this.features.remove(feature);
    }
}

public PersonalData getPersonalData() {
    return personalData;
}

public void setPersonalData(PersonalData personalData) {
    this.personalData = personalData;
}
}
//*******************************************************
//DefaultStudentModel
//*******************************************************
public class DefaultStudentModel extends StudentModel{
}
//*******************************************************
//FooStudentModel
//*******************************************************
public class FooStudentModel extends DefaultStudentModel {

public FooStudentModel(){
    System.out.println("Created an instance of FooStudentModel");
}

}
//*******************************************************
//StudentModelFactory class
//*******************************************************
public class StudentModelFactory {

 private List<Class<? extends StudentFeature>> featuresClasses;
private Class<? extends StudentModel> studentModelClass;

public StudentModelFactory(Class<? extends StudentModel> studentModelClass) {
    featuresClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends StudentFeature>>();
    setStudentModelClass(studentModelClass);
}
public void addFeatureClass(Class<? extends StudentFeature>  featureClass){
    if(!this.featuresClasses.contains(featureClass)){
        this.featuresClasses.add(featureClass);
    }
}

public void setStudentModelClass(
        Class<? extends StudentModel> studentModelClass) {
    this.studentModelClass = studentModelClass;
}


public StudentModel makeStudentModel() {
    StudentModel studentModel = null;
    try {
        studentModel = (StudentModel) studentModelClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return studentModel;
}
//****************************************************************************
    //This method is called to build all features for different student models
    //****************************************************************************
public void buildFeatures(StudentModel studentModel) {
    List<StudentFeature> updatedFeatures=new ArrayList<StudentFeature>();
    for(Class<? extends StudentFeature> featureClass:featuresClasses){
            try {
                Class<?>[] innerClasses=featureClass.getDeclaredClasses();

                for(Class innerClass:innerClasses){
                    try{
 ((StudentFeature.Builder<Builder>) innerClass.newInstance()).build(studentModel);                          
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

             }
    }
    studentModel.setFeatures(updatedFeatures);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just name the inner class `Builder`?

Comment: The reason I tried that way was because I had cast problem if builder in child feature do not extend builder in parent builder. This happened when I called constructor (Builder) ( innerClass.getConstructor(StudentModel.class).newInstance(studentModel)); I managed to make it work after your suggestion, but I had to change build method in Builder to be static, so I called innerClass.getMethod("build",StudentModel.class).invoke(null, studentModel);

Comment: Maybe it's out of scope of original post, but do you have any idea how can I make it possible that users could add additional parameters in their builders, and I'm still able to invoke all these builders from my method?

Comment: Uh, your inner class isn't static? That is some "news" honestly. Also, what is this model class you are talking about?

Comment: It is static. I updated original post and added the whole code. In earlier version, my build method was static, but now I managed to make it works if it's not static. Does this look ok, or it could be improved?